# Removing sections of a string with mixed symbols

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am developing a kill feed type program for a game server that has requested it.

For the most part everything is pretty straight forward except for the easiest way to clean up the following string:

`name1[1234567/12345678901234567] was killed by name2[12345/12345678901234567]`

Couple things to note:

- I need 2 separate strings from the original.
- 1 will be the 17 digit number after the first "/" and the second the 17 digits after the second "/"
- It is possible for the name1 or name2 to contain a "/" which is why I can't just use Index and the 17 digits after that.
- It is also possible for name1 or name2 to contain a "[CLAN]" which will throw off Index for the first "[" as well.
- The 17 digit number after the "/" will always be 17 digits, however, the number before it still inside the bracket will vary in length.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: I did it with regex: `(?<name1>.*?)\[.*?\/(?<id1>.*?)\] was killed by (?<name2>.*?)\[.*?\/(?<id2>.*?)\]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

`(?<name1>.*)\[(.*\/)?(?<val1>.*)\] was killed by (?<name2>.*)\[(.*\/)?(?<val2>.*)\]`

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sK2jF0/3)

On success, `Regex.Match` will return 2 groups: `val1` and `val2` which contains the values.

**Sample code**

```
var pattern = @"(?<name1>.*)\[(.*\/)?(?<val1>.*)\] was killed by (?<name2>.*)\[(.*\/)?(?<val2>.*)\]";
var input = @"name1[1234567/12345678901234567] was killed by name2[12345/12345678901234567]";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine("1st value = {0}, 2nd value = {1}", match.Groups["val1"], match.Groups["val2"]);
```

**Output**

1st value = 12345678901234567, 2nd value = 12345678901234567